# How to do Insert Into Select With SQLAlchemy from_select?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble specifically with using the from_select construct in SQLAlchemy.  I can't seem to get the syntax right for '`SELECT *`'.  Every example I've seen shows explicit column names. My issue is with the line below, I just can't get the syntax right :

```
meta.tables['XXXX'].insert().from_select(['*'],local_result)
```

I've seen an example like below but I can't translate it to select * for some reason:

```
sel = select([table1.c.a, table1.c.b]).where(table1.c.c > 5)
ins = table2.insert().from_select(['a', 'b'], sel)
```

Thanks!

```
import urllib
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy import or_

local_params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XXX;DATABASE=XXX;Trusted_Connection=yes")
local_engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % local_params)
local_conn = local_engine.connect()
local_result = local_conn.execute("select * from dbo.XXX")

cloud_params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=XXXXX;DATABASE=XXXX;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX")
cloud_engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % cloud_params)
cloud_conn = cloud_engine.connect()

meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=cloud_conn)

meta.tables['XXXX'].insert().from_select(['*'],local_result)

#Tried This Also But Doesn't Work
#cloud_conn.execute(meta.tables['XXXX'].insert().from_select(['*'],local_result))

local_conn.close()
local_result.close()
cloud_conn.close()
```

I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: FROM expression expected
```

Comment: can you add full stacktrace to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56400901/edit) it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .keys() to obtain all the columns of a select statement:

cloud_conn.execute(meta.tables['XXXX'].insert().from_select(local_result.keys(),local_result))

Answer (score 1):

Three years late to the party. Was looking for answer to this but could not find one online so I figured it through trial and error.

My answer is based on sqlalchemy 1.3x.

The insert -> from_select -> 'select *' combo is done as below:

```
sel = select([table1.c.a, table1.c.b]).where(table1.c.c > 5)
ins = table2.insert().from_select(sel.c, sel)
```

The statement **sel.c** somehow return the array of columns the question is looking for.